What enemies drop permanent stat boosts in Tsugunai: Atonement?
In the PlayStation 2 RPG Tsugunai: Atonement, what enemies will drop permanent stat boosting items (Walnuts of Power, Fruits of Life, Seeds of Speed, and Mental Mushrooms) and where can I fight them?
